# Indentation position in docker-compose.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I want to set up a Rails environment with Docker, but I get the following error.
I believe the indentation is incorrect, but I don't know which part. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
$docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=mysql

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.mysql: 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'
services.mysql.environment contains an invalid type, it should be an object, or an array
```

docker-compose.yml ↓

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.16
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The indentation for `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is wrong. It should be nested in the environment. Feel free to use the following.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.16
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    tty: true
```